# Array of textures performance impact

Tags: glsl, vulkan, fragment-shader, texture2d

Following [Kyle Halladay's tutorial on "Using Arrays of Textures in Vulkan Shaders"](http://kylehalladay.com/blog/tutorial/vulkan/2018/01/28/Textue-Arrays-Vulkan.html) I managed to make my code work.

At some point, Kyle says:

> "I don’t know how much (if any) of a performance penalty you pay for using an array of textures over a sampler2DArray." (cit.)

I'm concerned about performance. This is the shader:

```c
#version 450
#extension GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects : enable

layout(binding = 1) uniform sampler baseSampler;
layout(binding = 2) uniform texture2D textures[2];

layout(location = 0) in vec2 inUV;
layout(location = 1) flat in vec4 inTint;
layout(location = 2) flat in uint inTexIndex;

layout(location = 0) out vec4 outColor;

void main()
{
    outColor = inTint * texture(sampler2D(textures[inTexIndex], baseSampler), inUV);
}
```

The part I'm concerned about is `sampler2D(textures[inTexIndex], baseSampler)`, where it looks like a `sampler2D` is set up based on `baseSampler`. This looks horrendous and I don't know if it's per-fragment or if `glslc` can optimize it away, somehow.

Does someone know how much of an impact `sampler2D()` has?

> **Obsolete question which received answers in the comments**: What if I bind an array of `VkSampler` descriptors (`VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_SAMPLER`) in place of the `VkImageView` descriptors (`VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_SAMPLED_IMAGE`)? The shader wouldn't index into a `texture2D` array but into a `sampler2D` array with attached *ImageInfo* (the textures).

Also, are these kinds of optimizations crucial or are they irrelevant?

---

**EDIT:** cleaned up original question without changing the meaning, added same/corollary question with better wording below.

I apologize for my English.

What does this specific piece of code do:

```
texture(sampler2D(textures[inTexIndex], baseSampler), inUV)
```

Is this executed **per-fragment**? And if so, is the `sampler2D()` a function? A type cast? A constructor that allocates memory? This "function" is what I'm concerned about most. I presume indexing is inevitable.

In the comment I wonder if, as an alternative, I could use `VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_COMBINED_IMAGE_SAMPLER` descriptors and have an array of `sampler2D` in the shader. Would this choice increase performance?

Finally, I wonder if switching to a `sampler2Darray` really makes much difference (performance-wise).

Comment: "*The shader wouldn't index into a texture2D array but into a sampler2D array with attached ImageInfo (the textures).*" No, that would be an array of `sampler`. A `sampler2D` is a 2D texture + a sampler object. A `sampler` is *just the sampler*, no texture at all. `sampler` in GLSL maps to `VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_SAMPLER`.

Comment: And what about `VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_COMBINED_IMAGE_SAMPLER`? Does it map to `sampler2D`? Any hints about performance or what happens per-fragment? In "C++ speech", Is it like an instantiation `new Sampler2D()` or more like a cast `(sampler2D)`?

Comment: I use renderdoc to roughly check how much time shaders take. Also, the sampler is the state which determines how sampling is done, and texture is the memory, the image where it is done. `texture()` needs to know both, so they are combined into a sampler2D. How it happens is likely implementation dependent. And ye, combined image sampler is sampler2D.

Comment: It's not clear which aspect of this you are talking about. Are you talking about the use of separate texture and sampler state (ie: not a `COMBINED_IMAGE_SAMPLER`), or are you talking about the cost of indexing a texture from an array?

Comment: @NicolBolas thank you for your time. I see that here and on the Khronos forums you're pretty busy, so I understand that every second counts. Thanks for every drop of gold you're giving to the community :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cost of not using combined image/sampler objects will of course depend on the hardware. However, consider this.

HLSL, from Shader Model 4 onwards (so D3D10+) has *never* had combined image/samplers. They've [always used separate texture and sampler objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3dhlsl/dx-graphics-hlsl-to-type).

So if an entire API has been doing this for over a decade, it's probably safe to say that this is not going to be a performance problem.